# Div that contains jQuery won't center behind another div

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having trouble with centering of a div that contains Jquery.
It supposed to be the header behind all other content, but I can't get it there.
I tried z-index and variants of positions, but none of them works.

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Here's my code:

[Code JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vr8wG/)

> HTML:
>
> ```html
> <div id="container">
> <div id="mads"></div>
> <div id="slideshow">
>     <img src="image1.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 1" class="active" />
>     <img src="image2.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 2" />
>     <img src="image3.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 3" />
>     <img src="image4.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 4" />
> </div>
> ```
>
> CSS:
>
> ```css
> #slideshow {
>     height:350px;
>     width:1100px;
>     z-index:9;
> }
>
> #slideshow IMG {
>     position:absolute;
>     top:0;
>     left:0;
>     z-index:8;
>     opacity:0.0;
> }
>
> #slideshow IMG.active {
>     z-index:10;
>     opacity:1.0;
> }
>
> #slideshow IMG.last-active {
>     z-index:9;
> }
>
> body{
>     background-color:#000;
> }
>
> #container{
>     width:1124px;
>     height:768px;
>     margin-left:auto;
>     margin-right:auto;
> }
>
> #mads{
>     width:1124px;
>     height:768px;
>     margin-left:auto;
>     margin-right:auto;
>     background-image:url(file:///schijfje/Users/502034/Desktop/mappen/Stage/03.%20Mads%20Wittermans/web.png);
>
>     background-repeat:no-repeat;
>     z-index:100;
> }
>
> .header{
>     margin-left:auto;
>     margin-right:auto;
>     z-index:1;
>     position:absolute;
> }
> ```
>
> JS:
>
> ```js
> function slideSwitch() {
>     var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');
>
>     if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');
>
>     var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
>         : $('#slideshow IMG:first');
>
>     $active.addClass('last-active');
>
>     $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
>         .addClass('active')
>         .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
>             $active.removeClass('active last-active');
>         });
> }
>
> $(function() {
>     setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
> });
> ```

**EDIT:**

Issue is solved:
I gave the div that contains jQuery and the other div above a absolute position and a z-index. Now the divs are positioned behind each other.

Comment: Why do you have HTML in the JavaScript-window in your fiddle? That won't work.

Comment: I am not able to see anything...its just a blackscreen!

Comment: I'm not very familiar with jsFiddle, just using it so people can see my code... If this is really not working, I also can put my code into the post.

Comment: have you tried using float instead of absolute?

Comment: as Chris says, why would you have script inside <div></div>
though it's not a mistake, it may cause your problem & it's not advisable too

Comment: It might be something I am missing here but I see nothing in your code or CSs that would center that div on anything, finding the position of some OTHER element and positioning upon that.

Comment: that doesn't work, but i tried something with absolute positioning after your comment and that works for me! I gave the div that contains Jquery and the div with the other content bove a absolute position and a Z-index!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that works.
http://jsfiddle.net/marqs/cn8UJ/

The code had a couple of problems (or so strange solutions that I'm guessing they're unintentional)

1) header should be a `<header>`-tag, not a div. You can have the scripts inside a div, but it usually doesn't make much sense. Well except if you can only inject code to specific parts in DOM like through a CMS or something.

2) Your code was just functions defined, the setInterval was never called. What you probably wanted to do was

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 // this code gets run when DOM is loaded
 setInterval(slideSwitch, 5000);
});
```

This binds an event-listener that is triggered when DOM is ready. This is usually the time you want to run your code.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I shall take a good look to my code again!